# HTML textarea with <script> tags in it

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, textarea

I'm trying to make a textarea (`name="google_analytics_code"`) that will save in the DB the google analytics script. The problem is that it will not even POST anything (`$_POST['google_analytics_code'] = ""`) if I paste the script from google with script tags in it.

How can I make the textarea to be posted with the whole script (including script tags)?

Comment: What's "the google analytics script"? the raw js code loaded from google-analytics.com? The initialization code that sets your analytics account info?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems pasting any kind of text you want in a textarea. It would help to see your code that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/osatat) for a demo.

If it's not working, it would help to see code — an example of a stripped-down HTML page and PHP script that reproduce the problem.